# Problems with some characters

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I was having problems with this character: `’`

It displays as some rhombus like gibberish.

To fix this, I added `$content =mb_convert_encoding($content,'UTF-8');` before displaying.

Now it doesn’t display the gibberish and the character `’` either.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please do `var_dump(unpack('C*', $str))` with `$str` being that character from `$content`.

Comment: http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet

Comment: @Gumbo, displays this error: Warning: unpack() [function.unpack]: Invalid format type. In addition, i am looking for a solution that will work for other characters that i have not noticed yet

Comment: @BalusC , thanks; have gone through the page; cannot seem to figure it out yet

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure to set the page charset to UTF-8 in the header
2. If you write these signs in the document itself, make sure to save it as UTF-8
3. If you store them in a database, make sure to have the table charset set to UTF-8 and write to and read from the database with the same charset.